# 301 Rewrite Permanent Redirect in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04

Hi still learning linux (running ubuntu 10.04 lts) & nginx (running 1.4.1)thanks for any help, I have found examples of what I want to do but they don't spell it out enough for my comfort level..

I moved site1.com and all it's contents to site2.com and need a permanent 301 redirect as I have many links on other websites I cannot change.

The best tutorial I have found has told me to do something like this:

```
### redirect beta.cyberciti.biz$URI to www.cyberciti.biz$URI with 301 ###
server {
    listen      75.126.153.206:80;
    server_name beta.cyberciti.biz;
    root        /usr/local/nginx/html;
    index       index.html;
    rewrite     ^ $scheme://www.cyberciti.biz$request_uri permanent;
    # ....
}
```

however I am confused as to whether I add this whole block changing the variables or if I am supposed to change a server { .... } block that is already in my conf file.  I have two server { ... } in my conf file but they are both commented out (see below).. not sure why they are there if they are commented out..

```
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:110;
#         protocol   pop3;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
#
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:143;
#         protocol   imap;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
```

Current nginx.conf is:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  3;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;
tcp_nodelay        on;

gzip  on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}



# mail {
#     # See sample authentication script at:
#     # http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#     # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#     # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#     # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:110;
#         protocol   pop3;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
# 
#     server {
#         listen     localhost:143;
#         protocol   imap;
#         proxy      on;
#     }
# }
```

I inserted what you told me below the http{} block and above all the commented blocks.

Answer (score 4):

In nginx change `server_name` from site1 to site2 and then create a new site1 block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.com;
    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://site2.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this when I add that:  
    root@mail ~: service nginx restart
    Restarting nginx: [emerg]: unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:31
    configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: I already moved all the files so I haven't deleted the domain zone off my server but the files and folders are gone.. could that be the problem?

Comment: are you placing the `server` inside another `server`? cause that won't work, you need to create it outside the other `server` block, could you paste the whole `nginx.conf` or at least the part that's about this site?

Comment: no, I inserted it below the last http{} block and above all the commented blocks, added my nginx.conf to original post, thanks for your help!

Comment: well `server` blocks need to be inside `http` blocks, and if you see in the last line in the `http` block it says `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` that means you can create files inside `sites-enabled` and it would be included automatically, you don't need to play with the `nginx.conf` file, anyway if you want a fast fix, move the `server` block you added inside the `http` block